Bone colors missing in Armature tab
I'm watching a tutorial where the teacher is showing me how to change the bone colors on the armature tab. There should be colors for me to select from but there isn't.  Instead this is only found in the bone itself.  I don't want to do this because I want the group I've assigned the bone to be all be in that color.
Mine:

It should look like this:

Is there something I need to check or add-on?
Thanks.

Hello, maybe it's not possible with the new bone collection system and you need to select the bones and go into the Bone panel?

Might be worth reading the section on Bone Collections in the Blender manual since the tutorial you are watching is obviously for an earlier Blender version. CGDive has done a tutorial on the changes in Blender 4 including bone colours.

You can't color the bones in the Bone Groups list (now called Bone Collections) anymore, you need to switch to Edit, select the bones of a collection (press the Select button at the bottom of the list or shortcut ShiftG > Bone Collection) then go into the Bone panel > Viewport Display, press Alt+LMB on the Bone Color dropdown menu in order to choose the color for the selected bones. Switch to Pose mode if you want to assign a different color for this mode:

